# SQL Select director of many employees

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with teamID which is the ID of one Team, and the USERID are the members of that team. And then I have a USERID which is Coordinator.
My problem now is how to do a Query to give the name of coordinator per user.

```
userID | coordinator   
19     |         69    
4      |         69
```

[image]

Comment: Show your expected output.

Comment: @dfundako is there in the exemple i put

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a Common Table Expression (CTE):

```
;WITH Coordinators AS
  (SELECT TeamID, UserID
   FROM dbo.Teams
   WHERE IsCoordinator = 1)
SELECT t.UserID, c.UserID as CoordinatorID
FROM dbo.Teams t
INNER JOIN Coordinators c ON t.TeamID = c.TeamID
WHERE t.IsCoordinator = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

With a join of the table to the query of the coordinators:

```
select
  t.userid,
  c.userid coordinator
from tablename t inner join (
  select * from tablename
  where iscoordinator = 'True'
) c on c.teamid = t.teamid
```

The design you present may have for one user multiple coordinators since each user may belong to multiple teams.

Comment: It work to :) , except the 69 is included in both columns.

Comment: Is there a case that a user in one team may be coordinator in another team?

Comment: Yes, it can happen @forpas

Comment: And of course the coordinator of the team is also a user of that team. If you want to exclude that last case add: `where t.userid<>c.userid`

Answer (score 0):

So you've got to first find the team ID of the user who you want to find the coordinator of. Use this team ID to find all entries in your table with UserId, TeamId and isCoordinator. And a "isCoordinator is true" condition to only get the coordinator of the team.

```
SELECT UserId, name 
FROM teamTable 
WHERE TeamID in (
                 SELECT TeamID 
                 FROM usersTable 
                 WHERE UserID = IdOfTheUserInQuestion
                ) AND IsCoordinator = 'true';
```